# How use array and add multiple enties in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

My teacher wanted me to make a program based on An Employee which includes -

`His Name`
`His Id`
`His Sallary`

and we needed to make this using - Structures & Functions & Array as we are not that good in C++ so we just make simple programs . the code of the program i made is below , [ http://pastebin.com/9UFFJseN ]

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct employee
{
    char empname[40];
    int empid,empsalary;
}; employee e1;

void add_record(void);
void display_record(void);
void search_record(void);
void welcome();
void exito();


void main()
{

clrscr();

int choice,id;
cout<<"Welcome to Employee Info Menu by Rohit Jalan \n\n\n";
cout<<"1 -> Add Record\n";
cout<<"2 -> Display Record\n";
cout<<"3 -> Search Record\n";
cout<<"4 -> Exit";
cout<<"\n\t\t --> ";
cin>>choice;
switch(choice)
{
 case 1: add_record();break;
 case 2: display_record();break;
 case 3: search_record();break;

 case 4: exito();
}

getch();
}


void add_record()
{
clrscr();
cout<<"You have pressed 1\n\n\n";
cout<<"Please enter employee name : ";
gets(e1.empname);
cout<<"Please enter the employee id : ";
cin>>e1.empid;
cout<<"Please enter the employee salary : ";
cin>>e1.empsalary;
cout<<" \n \n \n \n";
main();
}

void display_record()
{clrscr();
cout<<"\nEmployee Name is : ";
puts(e1.empname);
cout<<"\nEmployee ID is : ";
cout<<e1.empid;
cout<<"\nEmployee salary is : ";
cout<<e1.empsalary;
getch();
main();
}

void search_record()
{int id;
clrscr();
cout<<"Please enter the id of the employee\n: ";
cin>>id;
   if(id==e1.empid)
   {
   display_record();
   }

   else cout<<"\nRecord not found...";
   getch();
   main();

}


void exito()
{clrscr();

cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t Thank you. ";
cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t Program by \n\n\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t";
delay(500);cout<<"ROHIT";
delay(500);cout<<" JALAN";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t";
delay(500);cout<<"Roll No";
delay(500);cout<<" 11436";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t";
delay(500);cout<<"Class";
delay(500);cout<<" XI-D";

delay(500);cout<<"....";
delay(100);
exit(0);
}
```

And now my teacher is asking me what if she wishes to enter more then 1 record of data and display more then 1 , or you can say she wants to decide that how much she wants to enter and display , as i am unable to solve her problem i request you all guys to help me in a simple and easy manner as i`m newbie out here . Please don't delay in answer i have a practical examination on 27th Feb 2015 . if you are unable to see my coding - 
http://pastebin.com/9UFFJseN#

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: Before you get to that (hint: what do you know about arrays?): why are you calling `main` from other functions?

Comment: sir by doing this i am able to go to main menu once again , so to choose other options like , show data , search , exit . 
sorry for giving such a dumb question im a complete newbie here .

Comment: That's what loops are for.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform actions more than once, you need a loop.

```
unsigned int Display_Menu(void)
{
  unsigned int selection = 0;
  while (selection != 4)
  {
    static const char menu_text[] = 
       "\n"
       "Welcome to Employee Info Menu by Rohit Jalan \n\n\n"
       "1 -> Add Record\n"
       "2 -> Display Record\n"
       "3 -> Search Record\n"
       "4 -> Exit\n"
       "\t\t --> ";
    cout.write(menu_text, sizeof(menu_text) - 1);
    cin >> selection;
    if ((selection >= 1) && (selection <= 4))
    {
       break;
    }
    cout << "\nInvalid selection, try again.\n";
    }
  return selection;
}
```

The above function displays a menu and if the User enters an invalid choice, it will print the menu again.  After a valid choice is received, the function returns to the caller.

This is an example of doing something more than once.

So if your instructor wants to perform more than one action, how would you do it?

**Edit 1:**
In general a Menu consists of two pieces:  1) Displaying the selections and 2) Processing the choices.  The above code handles the displaying of the selections.

```
// Forward declarations  
void Add_Record(void);
void Display_Record(void);
void Search_Record(void);

void Process_Choices(void)
{
  unsigned int choice = 0;
  do
  {
    choice = Display_Menu();
    switch (choice)
    {
      case 1:  Add_Record(); break;
      case 2:  Display_Record(); break;
      case 3:  Search_Record(); break;
    }
  } while (choice != 4);
}
```

The above function displays the menu, calls functions according to the User's selection and repeats.  It ends when the User enters the number 4.

Again, notice the loop construct that is used for performing actions more than once.